# Undefined offset: 2 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

when i try to save multiple records to database i get this error

> Undefined offset: 2

My Store Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $course = Course::create($request->all());

    $lessons = $request->except(['_token','_method']);
    for($x = 0;$x <= count($lessons); $x++)
    {
        $lesson = CourseClass::create([
            'course_id' => $course->id,
            'class_name' => $lessons['class_name'][$x],
            'class_desc' => $lessons['class_desc'][$x],
            'video' => $lessons['video'][$x],
            'files' => $lessons['files'][$x],
            'free' => $lessons['free'][$x],
        ]);
        $lesson->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$x < count($lessons)`

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: SO output `$lessons`, `$course` and see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($x = 0;$x < count($lessons['class_name']); $x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index iterator is not compatible with your usage. You're getting a count of request params, and trying to use that to access the array values of each param.

```
$request->except(['_token','_method'])
```

probably returns something like:

```
[
  'class_name' => ['namea', 'nameb'],
  'class_desc' => ['desca', 'descb'],
  'video' => ['vida', 'vidb'],
  'files' => ['filesa', 'filesb'],
  'free' => [true, false],
]
```

So, `count($lessons)` will return (pretending my example is exactly accurate) `5`. Whereas you're probably looking for `2` (the size of the sub arrays).

You could do as @tech suggests, and get the count from one of these sub arrays for your indexing instead:

```
count($lessons['class_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $course = Course::create($request->all());

    $lessons = $request->except(['_token','_method']);
    for($x = 0;$x <= count($lessons); $x++)
    {
        $lesson = CourseClass::create([
            'course_id' => $course->id,
            'class_name' => $lessons[$x]['class_name'],
            'class_desc' => $lessons[$x]['class_desc'],
            'video' => $lessons[$x]['video'],
            'files' => $lessons[$x]['files'],
            'free' => $lessons[$x]['free'],
        ]);
        $lesson->save();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps :)